# Why my Bitcoin Cash coins moved to another wallet if i did it on original Bitcoin on 12/12/2017?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I have very old Bitcoin wallet from 2012 year. The last operation was 12/12/2017 - this was movement all sum to my another wallet.

I was very surprised today when i first time load this wallet into Bitcoin-ABC (bitcoin cash) and see this transaction inside it!!! I see exactly same transaction (moving same sum to same wallet alias on same date 12/12/2017) inside Bitcoin Cash blockchain.

Can you explain me how is it possible? As I understand Bitcoin Cash has separate blockchain from August 2017 so i should not see the last operation on December 2017.

I used this command to load my wallet into Bitcoin-ABC (bitcoin cash)
bitcoin-abc-0.16.1/bin/bitcoin-qt -wallet=my_bitcoin_wallet.dat -datadir=path_to_bitcoin_cash_blockchain

Comment: yes, the btc-blockchain and the bch-blockchain are running independently of each other. the most probable cause is: your wallet was hacked or you did an mistake. if you send a transaction to the btc-network it is absolutely impossible that this transaction will be executed on the bch-blockchain -> accept you (or somebody else who knows your private key) send the transaction to the bch-network

Comment: @anion I'm sure it was not hacked. Because hacker should move all sum to his own wallet but not into my. And another reason is hacker can do it any date but bth-transaction was done exactly 12/12/2017

Comment: "hacker should move all sum to his own wallet" that is obviously correct, i thought the same when i have written it :D

Comment: @anion I found very interesting info. It is unconfirmed as i can see. So I think this is bitcoin-qt bug or some behaviour which i can't understand when it show this transaction from original btc-blockchain. I see this info when double click on the last tran
Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool
Date: 12/12/17 13:13
To: 
Debit:
Transaction fee:
 ....

Comment: Would you be willing to share the transaction ID?

Answer (score -1):

> I see exactly same transaction (moving same sum to same wallet alias
>   on same date 12/12/2017) inside Bitcoin Cash blockchain. Can you
>   explain me how is it possible?

Bitcoin and BitcoinCash have the same history before August'17

Comment: i know. That is my question why can I see transaction which was on December'17

Comment: You should use separate wallet.dat file for BCH network. Make a backup file, put `wallet_for_bch.dat` to BCH folder and run client with -zapwallettxes=2 parameter (and all other command-line arguments also!) to rescan the blockchain